# WPF MVVM vs Razor Page MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asp.net-core, mvvm

MVVM pattern in WPF has a strong emphasis on completely separating the ViewModel from the UI, and ideally has nothing or very little in the code-behind file. This allows to re-use the ViewModel for different types of interface.

MVVM pattern in Razor Pages has the code-behind as the ViewModel and is tightly coupled with the web logic with OnGet and OnPost methods.

Thus, the carefully-crafted decoupled WPF ViewModel cannot serve as the Web ViewModel (or perhaps can be used *from* the web page Model?)

Is there something I'm missing, and why is there such a difference between MVVM in WPF (decoupled) and MVVM in Razor Pages (coupled)?

If we were to apply the Razor Pages approach to WPF, then the code-behind would become the ViewModel -- which I've never seen anyone recommend.

Comment: As far as I know, MVVM is about decoupling **Models** from **Views**, not **ViewModels** from **Views** :\

Answer (score 2):

To make things clear: WPF introduces a coupling between the view and the view model the same way Razor Pages does. The view model is a data representation layer in order to break the dependency between the view and the model. So the view can be changed without modifying any models. The view model itself is then coupled to the model since it fetches the required data (e.g. from a service or data base). 
This behavior is realized in Razor Pages in a unified pattern by having the view models implement the abstract `PageModel` and by following a convention by providing the appropriate optional action handlers (e.g. OnGet()). Those handlers will be invoked by the framework anytime a HTTP request was issued for the page. You would fetch or manipulate model data based on the request method (e.g. GET, DELETE, POST, PUT, ...) and then present it to the view. The convention describes the naming pattern of those handlers so that the framework can identify them.

So you'll find the same degree of coupling between the layers in WPF MVVM and Razor Pages MVVM. Since the view model in RazorPages encapsulates the context of a specific page the source file naming follows a naming convention ("page name.cshtml.cs") to make the relationship visible in your filesystem. It's not a code-behind file like the `partial` class file of a view in WPF.

Comment: _The view model is a data representation layer in order to break the dependency between the view and the model_ Not exactly true, you describe MVC. MVVM is to split VIew from presentation logic and to support two-way binding w/o spaghetti code from Windows Forms times (`txtName.Text` to read or set value). It was specifically introduced (and invented) by Microsoft for WPF. In WinForms you had a lot of code in the code-behind which was related to formatting values and retrieving/updating UI elements. MVVM was invented to solve that.In ASP.NET Core VM is just reduced to a DTO Class w/o any logic

Comment: Presentation logic in WPF/MVVM usually involves stuff like, updating other controls contents (solved via data binding and `INotifyPropertyChanged`), updating the state of text fields (active/inactive, buttons, handled via `ICommand` and `CanExecute`) or coordinating user input with background services (commands calling services to fetch or submit data - done by controllers in MVC). Most of that stuff isn't applicable to server-sided web applications (but can be applied to client-sided web applications). Goal of MVVM is to reuse that when UI changes or is reworked

Comment: MVVM is a form of MVP which is a form of MVC. I said DATA representation layer to emphasize that it's an intermediate layer to the model data itself. The main goal of MVVM (same goal as MVP, MVC) is to decouple view from model or business logic. Data binding is just the mechanism to realize this. It's a variation of MVP that uses binding to make the dependency between Presenter (or Controler) and View unidirectional.

Comment: Nope, DataBinding was the main reason why MVVM was introduced. There was no MVVM before WPF existed. It was specifically designed for WPFs data-binding features. Later the pattern was adopted to other frameworks, but it's originally designed for WPF and its data-bindings. It was invented/defined/described by Ken Cooper and Ted Peters, two Microsoft Engineers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–viewmodel#Rationale

Comment: I never said that MVVM existed before WPF. I just said it evolved from MVP. MVP like MVC have an dependency arrow pointing towards the view (in the dependency graph or the UML model). By introducing a binding mechanism, they managed to remove this arrow. The presenter became more decoupled from the view. In MVVM all dependency arrows are pointing into the same direction now and away from the view.

Comment: I have to add that MVVM is an architectural pattern. This means the goal of this pattern and patterns of its kind  is always to solve an architectural problem. In the case of MVVM it's the coupling of the application view to the business logic or the presentation layer to the business layer. Commands and Bindings are just the mechanisms introduced to realize and improved decoupling (compared to MVC and MVP). It feels that you have the wrong point of view when looking at those patterns. So your sentence must be "DataBinding is the main reason why MVVM COULD BE introduced" to be correct.

Comment: I always made it a partial class an I think it has to be.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you insist on using Razor Pages, when there is MVC (Model-View-Controller).

You should use the MVC pattern instead. You get the same razor syntax but decoupled.

Razor Pages were introduced as a form of successor to WebForms (which itself tried to mimic Windows Forms, which isn't about decoupling neither).

If we go a few years back in history, MVVM was to use the full power of WPF's Two-Way Model binding, which acts as a separate layer between the UI and Application layer where one can put presentation logic in (logic tightly coupled to the Presentation, which is an UI concern rather than application layer which is decoupled from the UI).

For that reasons the MVVM's ViewModels also have (additionally to properties for Model Binding), things like Commands and may be Navigation aware (i.e. via Prism's `INavigationAware` interfaces).

In this context, ViewModels aren't of much value in server-sided web applications, because HTTP by itself, is stateless where ViewModels maintain a state.

Thus the ViewModels in MVC are simply reduced to DTOs (Data Transfer Objects), which has basic validation (through validation attributes). ViewModels in MVC Applications don't have any presentation logic, due to the fact its rendered into HTML and most presentation Logic happens outside via JavaScript (what happens when a button is clicked, how to format a date or currency for a user).

That being said, you don't really need full-fleged ViewModels in an ASP.NET Core application, at least not for the server-sided part. However, if you are using a client-sided technology (Angular, Vue.js, React) you may utilize ViewModels to enhance the functionality and decouple it from the View.

In fact, [angular components](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components) are pretty much ViewModels and fulfill the same task as ViewModels in MVVM pattern do (one can inject services into it, has 1-way or 2-way bindings, input validation and one puts presentation logic in them).

**TL;DR**: You don't really need ViewModels as they are defined in MVVM, just DTO-like classes to make consuming them in the (Razor)View Template easier. And don't use Razor Pages for decoupling.

Comment: When I add `@model MyModel` to my view, doesn't that "couple" my view and model? Absolutely no difference between Razor Pages and MVC at that point. It's just expressed differently.

Comment: "Model" in MVC/MVVM is more than "DTO class". M-V-VM/M-V-C are layers, not concrete classes. For example, NavigationService is part of the View, even though its written in code. Its not like "View = XAML nothing else". Model in in the sense of MVC is "every thing that is not View or Controller", which includes also all your services. It depends though what you bind with `@model MyModel`. Binding your EF Entities? Thats the wrong way to go. Biding your DTOs/ViewModels? Then you're good

Comment: `@model MyModel` is nothing else than binding a ViewModel to `DataContext`, its just there to allow you strong typing and intellisense within the Razor View. On XAML you have ViewModel first and View-First approaches, both valid

Comment: If NavigationService is a plain service and not a view to a service its definitely not part of the presentation layer or view. It's part of the model. A service processes data or outputs data according to an input.

Comment: I've been reading a lot about MVC vs Razor pages, and most people were recommending Razor pages unless it's a web API or a single-page application. They say MVC controller classes grow like a virus and the code is spread into all kinds of places -- and in that sense Razor pages has cleaner separation of concerns. Even Microsoft is recommending Razor pages for websites based on page navigation.

Comment: @EtienneCharland You're right. They are an improvement compared to MVC driven applications. Razor Pages offer a cleaner encapsulation and an improved decoupling.

Comment: If WPF MVVM classes maintain state and Razor DTO is stateless, then there's no point in trying to re-use the ViewModels between them. Is it thus OK to have HTML formatting code in the Razor code-behind? In WPF, people would go as far as creating new classes for events args to fully decouple the ViewModel from WPF -- which in reality will only be useful to create another type of stateful UI like a Linux interface or perhaps an Android app that isn't based on a web API. It seems going the extra mile for strict decoupling of WPF from its ViewModel has little benefit in most cases.

Comment: @EtienneCharland The goal of MVVM, MVP or MVC patterns is not to reuse the controller or the view model but the business logic of your application. You don't want to modify your model evrytime you modify or replace your view. It also makes automated UI testing possible which also is a huge gain. When the view is coupled to the model the view can't be tested without it. Assuming that your model consists of services and data bases this can be a huge impact.

Comment: @EtienneCharland If you don't need testability or your application is small or UI will never change (e.g. design or new navigation paths or structure) you can fairly develop without those patterns. Your evaluation and your personal decision. The view model just makes it possible that the view doesn't have to directly access the model. It breaks the dependency. between those two. While at the same time the model doesn't have to care about the presentation of the data.

Comment: @EtienneCharland "... to fully decouple the ViewModel from WPF ...".  WPF is a framework. It's not possible to write a WPF application and decouple the view model from it. Your view model must at least implement either the ICommand or the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to have the intended fuctionality. This means if you like to reuse your application on another platform you have to recreate your view model and view (at least. Maybe your model too if .NET is not supported on the new platform).

Comment: When it comes to mapping event args to a custom type (I think that's the default approach promoted by Microsoft) in the ViewModel so that it doesn't depend on any WPF class, this changes nothing about testability. If the ViewModel isn't going to be re-used anyway, then this particular decoupling seems pointless. The class is still fully MVVM. Some people are afraid of using classes from the System.Windows namespace in their ViewModel.

Comment: @EtienneCharland I just can say that having custom events with custom Eventhandlers is quite common. If you need to pass more event data or more specific event data to the observer than it is quite common to extend EventArgs (which e.g. transports no data) and create your own args. Since Microsoft recommends that your custom event args derives from EventArgs you still have a dependency on this type. Since the Eventhandler<T> itself is part of the framework it is difficult to avoid any related framework types. And in this case it is useless.

Comment: @EtienneCharland If you don't want to depend on the frameworks event mechanism you can implement your own Observer Pattern but than you can't use events of framework classes anymore. In general since frameworks use the IoC principle you have to extend and use framework types. So when using a framework you will always have to use it's library. You can't omit this.A framework, once chosen, is one of your biggest issues in terms of extensibility or constraints. That's why choosing the right framework is important. Maybe sometimes it's better to avoid a framework at all.

Comment: @EtienneCharland A dependency on a framework means you depend on somebody others projects where you might have absolutely no influence. So if it is full of bugs or poorly maintained this gonna be your problem. If support stops this gonna be your problem.

Comment: @EtienneCharland I agree with you that avoiding framework code in order to make your code reusable with other frameworks is in case of the view model pointless. As long we are talking about the application framework itself your totally right.

Comment: _"... to fully decouple the ViewModel from WPF ...". WPF is a framework. It's not possible to write a WPF application and decouple the view model from it_ Just plain wrong. Done a couple of these, its not easy but ViewModels can (with a bit of work) be reused across WPF, UWP and Xamarin forms or Avalonoia (.NET Core portable UI, 3rd party https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/find/master), profing that ICommand/INotifyPropertyChanged are not tied to WPF alone

Comment: Yes, it *can* be reused for other state-persistent UI, but requires some extra work. Unless one plans to add other such UI, then it might not be worth doing the extra work to make it strictly decoupled. Tseng, if one decides later to add UWP or Avalonia, is it fairly easy to do the extra work then and tweak the existing ViewModel? I'm thinking mostly of event handlers. Is there something else that requires special attention? As for ASP.NET, putting complex HTML rendering logic in the ViewModel isn't a clean separation, but if it avoids more complex code in the page, then I see no real issue.

Comment: You don't use event handlers in MVVM (tight coupling).Pub/Sub (event aggregator) for inter VM communication, ICommand/INotifyPropertyChanged for commands and binding notifications. Nothing else. Easiest aye to enforce it is putting ViewModels into own assembly which doesn't reference any WPF or windows UI classes. No one said HTML goes into ViewModel, but in ASP.NET Core there is not much to "ViewModels", they just act as DTOs (you can't really have a lot of logic there, there are no commands in Razor views and binding doesnt require INPC, ViewModels in ASP.NET Core are just dataholders (DTOs)